# printf "\033[8;(width);(height)t" works for a specific height and width but is there something more universal

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape, maximize-window

I have a script which is for running as a first run script on different machines and I don't know ahead of time what the width/height of the monitors will be. What I hoping to find is a command like `printf "\033[8;(width);(height)t"` which is more universal and will expand the terminal to maximum no matter which size monitor is connected to the computer. I had an escape sequence that worked great, but I lost the script along with the code when one of my drives died (I know, backup, backup, and backup again) and can't seem to find that fix again anywhere.

Using the `printf "\033[8;(width);(height)t"` escape code sequence works if I know in advance what the height and width of the maximized monitor dimensions are (for instance using `printf "\033[8;58;238t"` will work on my 1920x1080 monitor just fine and will expand as expected) but it is not enough for a larger monitor. Using `tput cols` and `tput lines` will give me what the current window dimensions are, but not the maximum dimensions.

I know I can use the keyboard and mouse to do this, but I am strictly looking for something that will expand the window without any other input or key presses, if for no other reason than knowing how to do it and making it work. This needs to execute at the beginning of a bash script on a fresh Ubuntu flavor installation (the script does unique installations and updates). It might be able to work if I could figure out how to get the maximum terminal size possible of a screen into a variable to be used in the code mentioned above.

I have tried `echo -ne '\e[9;1t'` and `printf '\e[9;1t'`, also `echo -ne '\e[10;2t'` and `printf '\e[10;2t'` escape codes to no avail, mentioned at https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/ (Control Characters and Escape Sequences) on pages "[Alias: Maximize Terminal](https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_st-10/)" and "[Maximize Terminal Window](https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_st-9/)". This is one of the few references I can find. Any searching of various ways to ask this question doesn't seem to yield any results and they all seem to rely on knowing ahead of time what the maximum dimensions can be.

Any hints of what I can use for this would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: What if you use a number that's larger than your current screen?

Comment: E.g., 9999,9999?

Comment: I guess that will work. I didn't think of just putting a high number in there and let Linux say, "Wait a minute, I can't go that high! I'll just go as far as I can and leave it at that!" I tried it on my work laptop and then on my UHD TV and it seems to work just as I requested.This did work. I had thought about trying to emulate the F11 key press but I wanted to use something that's native to the builds (I can't guarantee that every new run will have network access) and would not have to rely on outside tool that would need to be installed before using. Thank you, simple and efficient.

Comment: I've added an answer for you to select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the size to a number that is guaranteed to be larger than any existing screen. Pad it some to accommodate for rapidly increasing screen resolutions:

```
printf "\033[8;99999;99999t"
```

The window manager should truncate the size to the maximum available area.